# Axios GraphQl query throws internal server error but fetch() works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, axios, gatsby

I am struggling to execute my first graphQl query with axios.

The app stack is Gatsby on the front-end with Symfony's API-Platform on the back end.

I did check a few the other similar questions at SO and blog posts but no luck.

The thing is that the query works on graphiQl AND it also works if I attempt to execute with fetch API.

This code is within `sagas.js`

Here's the

```
const api = (data) => {
  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: API_ROOT_GRAPHQL,
    data,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log('response axios', response);
    return response.data;
  });
};

function* getUserProfile(action) {
  const userId = `"/api/users/${action.payload.userId}"`;
  const queryQl = {
    query: `{ 
      user(id: ${userId}) {
        id
        username
        name
        email
        roles
      }
    }`,
  };

  try {
    yield put({
      type: GET_USER_PROFILE_INIT,
    });

    const data = yield call(api, queryQl);

    console.log('data user profile', data);

    yield put({
      type: GET_USER_PROFILE_OK,
      data: data.user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
```

As you can see below is throws error: `Cannot return null for non nullable field`

Thing is that the below fetch query works perfectly - as does graphiql - so I am wondering this must be some config issue on my axios request.

I also checked that the data posted to the API with the same with both axios et fetch, as below from Firefox dev tools Network-> params:

`query  { user(id: "/api/users/1") { id username name email roles } }`

```
const apiQl = (queryQl) => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(queryQl),
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log('rsponse fetch', response);
    return response.data;
  });
};
```

[image: console output from above console.log()]

EDIT: request header for `axios`

[image: request header from Firefox dev tools]

Comment: How is it "working perfectly" when the console clearly shows not only the error but also null for the user?

Comment: Look at the top of the image. It says "response axios" , coming from the console.log that can you see on the axios function. I wanted to show an output of the axios error.  The fetch function is indeed working perfectly, so no point in showing its output.

Comment: Somewhere your schema declares `username` as a non-nullable field (probably `String!`) on your User type, and the data your backend is providing in response to that query fails that condition. This may be because you're not setting a User ID or something, but this almost certainly has nothing to do with axios. Out of curiosity, why are you using a generator to fetch a user profile? This code seems wildly over-complicated for such a common routine.

Comment: @coreyward. Thanks. `username` is indeed non-nullable, but the same restriction is valid for the query coming from `graphiql` or from `fetch()` and they do not fail. So my guess is that some configuration specific to `axios`. Not sure I agree about the over-complication. The query function is quite straightforward and then it is part of a saga, which is very much boilerplate.

Comment: @BernardA You haven't shared anything showing you doing the same thing with `fetch`, and you haven't shared the request data. Telling us that those work and this doesn't is making it impossible for us to help you find the bug in your code.

Comment: @coreyward. May be it isn't clear enough, but info you mentioned is above. The `const apiQl`, placed just above the picture, is the corresponding `fetch()` function . The `axios` function is right on top of the post. So I alternatively use `const data = yield call(apiQl, queryQl);` or `const data = yield call(api, queryQl);` to switch in-between `fetch()` and `axios`. An instance of the query request data, from Firefox dev tools, is also shown just above the `const apiQl`. The data sent for `axios` is the same as the one for `fetch()`. I will add the full request headers to the post above.

Answer (score 0):

As both `graphiQl` and `fetch()` were working and `axios` was not, I was quick to point fingers at the latter. As it happens `axios` was the only one working properly.
As @coreyward suggested, there were restrictions on the server side, so that some `User` properties should only be available for query by their user owner, and `username` was not among them.
For those familiar with Symfony's API-Platform:

As an example, the `email` property was available, as it included the `get-owner` annotation.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180)
 * @Groups({"post", "put", "get-admin", "get-owner"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"post"})
 * @Assert\Email(groups={"post", "put"})
 * @Assert\Length(min=6, max=180, groups={"post", "put"})
 */
private $email;
```

But `username` did not include the `get-owner` group annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180)
 * @Groups({"post", "get-ad-with-user"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"post"})
 * @Assert\Length(min=6, max=50, groups={"post"})
 */
private $username;
```

So the fix was just to add that annotation to the `username` property as so:

```
 * @Groups({"post", "get-ad-with-user", "get-owner"})
```

It is unclear to me at this time on why did `fetch()` and `graphiQl` were able to fetch the data.